# Context getColor in activity and AndroidJunit4 return different result. Why?

Tags: android, android-instrumentation, android-junit

I'm getting color (i.e. `R.color.my_white` is `FFFFFFFF`
) from my resource as below

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.my_white)
```

And when I perform AndroidJUnit4 testing, I also get the same color.

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.my_white)
```

However their return value differs, where in the actual activity, it is -1, and in the Instrumental Test, it is 520093696. Why is that differing?

(I suspect that the instrumental test context return a different result)

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it. The `getContext()` in the AndroidJunit4 is not working correctly. So I use

```
 activityRule.activity.getColor(R.color.my_white)
```

Where `activityRule` is

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```